# how to remove json document display over the header of the web-site in wix

Tags: velo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zV4g.png)
in the above image you can see how the json file is displayed over the header. On the top it is displaying

```
body { background-color: lightblue; }
```

how to remove the json file from top of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Wix account and go to the Editor.

Click on the header section of your website.
Look for the element or code widget that is displaying the JSON document.

Click on the element or code widget to select it.
Press the Delete key on your keyboard to remove it.
Confirm the deletion if prompted.

Save your changes.

Preview your website to ensure the JSON file is no longer displayed in the header.

If the issue persists, review your site's code to ensure there are no residual references to the JSON document.

Publish your website to make the changes live.